# Android unable to read system file with cat command

Tags: android, shell, command-line, adb, exec

I'm trying to read two different system files on an Android phone by using the Linux "cat" command. Both files exist on the phone and can be read by using the Android Debug Bridge (ADB). The phone is not rooted. Both files and directories have the same permissions.

However, I can only read the first file by using the "cat" command in Java.
Do you have any idea what could be the issue?

```
XYZ:/ $ ls -ld /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 0 2021-01-16 17:18 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/

XYZ:/ $ ls -ld /sys/class/power_supply/battery/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 2021-01-16 17:18 /sys/class/power_supply/battery/

XYZ:/ $ ls -ld /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2021-01-16 17:22 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq

XYZ:/ $ ls -ld /sys/class/power_supply/battery/cycle_count
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2021-01-16 17:18 /sys/class/power_supply/battery/cycle_count
```

**Edit:**

```
XYZ:/ $ ls -dZ /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/
u:object_r:sysfs_devices_system_cpu:s0 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/
XYZ:/ $ ls -dZ /sys/class/power_supply/battery/
u:object_r:sysfs_batteryinfo:s0 /sys/class/power_supply/battery/
XYZ:/ $ ls -dZ /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
u:object_r:sysfs_devices_system_cpu:s0 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
XYZ:/ $ ls -dZ /sys/class/power_supply/battery/cycle_count
u:object_r:sysfs_batteryinfo:s0 /sys/class/power_supply/battery/cycle_count
```

Comment: *"Both files and directories have the same permissions"* not true, check `ls -dZ`

Comment: I see, there is a different SELinux context type. I didn't know about that. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if an app can be allowed to read such a file in the same way as ADB does? Or is this just possible on rooted devices?

Comment: with some [trick](https://www.xda-developers.com/tasker-5-9-2-beta-run-adb-shell-commands-without-tethered-pc) you can run as user shell, but i have no clue about app development. i guess there is some API for what you looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start bash script on boot not rooted Android 7.0 and Android 9.0 device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221007/start-bash-script-on-boot-not-rooted-android-7-0-and-android-9-0-device)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is, that through ADB shell, I can get the info easily by using cat on /sys/class/power_supply/battery/cycle_count. But using cat within the app on the same file doesn't work. Obvisously, the different SELinux context types are blocking it...

Comment: the reason is each app have it's own uid/gid and furthermore running in isolated namespaces. user 2000 (shell) can run with special privileges, that's how tasker does the trick via adb

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this means, that the file will not be readable from within the app...

Comment: you don't need this file you need some API providing the same information

Comment: Thank you. I'll go for a BatteryManager API feature enhancement request

Comment: there are two apps mentioned Ampere and AccuBattery maybe you can reverse code https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232920

Comment: I'll give it a try